# Paged within a custom content type template

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, pagination

I'm having a huge problem a custom query within a custom post type template with regards to pagination.

For some reason, the previous post, next post links are showing blank.
If I do "www.domainname.com/wolf/spot/paged/2/ it shows a 404 page.

The code is below... as I said above, this is a custom query, WITHIN a custom post type template.

```
<div id="content">

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <h1 class="pageName"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <div class="entry">
            <?php the_content('<p class="serif">Read the rest of this entry &raquo;</p>'); ?>

            <!-- BEG Wolf Logs -->

            <h3>Recent Logs for <?php the_title(); ?>:</h3>

            <?php
            wp_reset_postdata();
            $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

            if (isset($_GET['show'])) {
                $ppp = $_GET['show'];
            } else {
                $ppp = 10;
            }

            if (isset($_GET['archyear'])) {
                $archYear = $_GET['archyear'];
            } else {
                $archYear = date("Y");
            }

            $wolf = strtolower(get_the_title());
            $logArgs = array(
                        'post_type' => 'wolf-log',
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
                        'meta_key' => 'observationDate',
                        'posts_per_page'=> $ppp,
                        'meta_query' => array(
                                            'relation' => 'AND',
                                            array(
                                                'key' => 'wolf',
                                                'value' => $wolf,
                                                'compare' => '='
                                            ),
                                            array(
                                                'key'       => 'observationDate',
                                                'type'      => 'numeric',
                                                'value'     => array($archYear.'0101',$archYear.'1231'),
                                                'compare'   => 'BETWEEN'
                                            )
                                        ),
                        'order' => 'DESC',
                        'paged' => $paged
            );


            $wlQuery = new WP_Query($logArgs);

            if ($wlQuery->have_posts()) {
                while ($wlQuery->have_posts()) {
                    $wlQuery->the_post();
                    get_template_part('loop', 'wolflogs');
                } // endwhile


            ?>

            <div id="postFooter">
                <div class="navigation">
                    <p><?php next_posts_link('&lt; Older Posts', $wlQuery->max_num_pages); ?></p>
                    <p><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Posts &gt;', $wlQuery->max_num_pages); ?></p>
                </div>
            <?php   
            } else {
                echo '<h2>No current logs, check back later.</h2>';
            }

            // Restore original Post Data
            wp_reset_postdata();
            ?>
            <div class="pageControls">
                <?php
                    $archArray = array();
                    $archArgs = array(
                                'post_type'         => 'wolf-log',
                                'post_status'       => 'publish',
                                'meta_key'          => 'wolf',
                                'meta_value'        => $wolf,
                                'order'             => 'DESC',
                                'posts_per_page'    => -1
                                );

                    $archQuery = new WP_Query($archArgs);

                    if ($archQuery->have_posts()) {
                        while($archQuery->have_posts()) {
                            $archQuery->the_post();
                            $obDate = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'observationDate', true);
                            $obDate = strtotime($obDate);
                            $obDate = date("Y", $obDate);
                            $archArray[$obDate] = $obDate;
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo 'No Archives';
                    }

                    wp_reset_postdata();
                    ?>

                    <div class="styled-select">

                        <select name="archivesPager" id="archivesPager">
                            <option value="">Archive</option>
                            <?php
                                arsort($archArray);
                                foreach($archArray as $archYear) {
                                    echo '<option value="?archyear='.$archYear.'">'.$archYear.'</option>';
                                }
                            ?>

                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearFix"></div>
            </div><!-- END postFooter -->

            <?php
            // Restore original Post Data
            wp_reset_postdata();

            ?>
            <!-- END Wolf Logs -->

        </div>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>

    <p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>
```

```
</div>
```

Comment: Well for one thing you have wp_reset_postdata everywhere.  I see it being called after the start of loop why?  Try removing all instances of that and put it at the end once after the endwhile statement and before the else:

Comment: That was a desperate attempt to fix it.  I just removed it and it still is no-go.

Comment: Also since you're building your own custom loop, why do you still need the standard loop wrapping it?

Comment: Good Question.  The Standard Loop is a "Wolf Profile" page, which has info on the wolf itself.  The custom loop is for a different custom type called a "Wolf Log" which is basically journal entries for that particular wolf.  Hence, the need for one within another.

Comment: Try putting your next_posts_link and previous_posts_link OUTSIDE of your custom while loop

Comment: I think it already is..sorry because your code is not well formatted, it is hard for us to see it clearly...

Comment: It is already outside the code... I just have a lot going on here.

Comment: Also, this code is working fine on a standard "page" template, just not on the single-wolf.php template.

Answer (score 0):

> Also, this code is working fine on a standard "page" template, just not on the single-wolf.php template.

Paging does not work in a single template page. Single pages use the `<!--next page-->` tag to use paging.

The global variables used are different. The global variable `$page` is used in a single post (or page) to do paging instead of `$paged` which is used with other pages.

The next and previous link functions rely on the `$paged` global variable. Sometimes you can trick WordPress by setting `$paged` to the value of `$page`:

```
$paged = $page;
```

Place it above this line:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

EDIT:

You may also need to change the query variable here:

```
'paged' => $paged
```

TO:

```
'page' => $paged
```

Comment: I'm looking at paging the sub-query. I'm going to have to try something else.